# error: ‘father’ is an inaccessible base of ‘son’

Tags: c++, oop

Why am I not able to create a pointer of base class and point it to child class when access modifiers are put as private or protected ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class father
{
     public:
     int n=10;
};

class son:protected father
{
public:
    son(){
        cout<<n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    father *f;
    f=new son;
}
```

Comment: Let me ask you this: If the class has a protected member, can it be accessed from outside of the class?

Comment: nope as only public members are allowed to be accessed from outside

Comment: Note: Protected inheritance is usually a bug. It very rarely is what you actually want. Composition or private inheritance is more likely to be what you *actually* want.

Comment: @KaranSingh Okay, so lets extend that to the base class.  If it is protected, should we be able to access it, i.e. get pointer to it?

Comment: aren't we accessing the child class using the pointer of base class and not vice versa?? @NathanOliver

Comment: In your code you are trying to store the child class, using a pointer to it's base.  See how that is a problem?

Comment: Why would you expect it to work like this? What difference should private/protected/public inheritance make? Sorry, but the reason you can't do that is because the language doesn't allow it. BTW: Check out Liskov Substitution Principle. According to that, a derived class instance is also a base class instance. So, applying that logic to your code, a son is a father which doesn't make sense if you translate that to human relationships. Avoid such linguistic conflicts, like they are also present in the terms "parent class" and "child class".

Answer (score 4):

A protected member of a class is accessible by the class itself and it's children. A similar logic applies to protected inheritance. That is, when you have a protected inheritance only the class and it's children are "aware" of such inheritance. Hence, with your code (use of protected inheritance), you could easily cast son to father within the son class as shown it what follows.

```
class father
{
public:
  int n = 10;
};
class son : protected father
{
void tmp(){father *f = new son;}
public:
  son()
  {
    cout << n;
  }
};
```

However, to achieve what you wish to achieve, you must use public inheritance (to make it possible for others to be "aware" of the existence of such inheritance).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class father
{
public:
  int n = 10;
};
class son : public father
{
public:
  son()
  {
    cout << n;
  }
};
int main()
{
  father *f;
  f = new son;
}
```

Comment: @Yksisarvinen. Indeed. Changed accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: how can I use both protected inheritance and method overriding at the same time ?

Comment: @Chipster. I *think*, it should and it's actually a very interesting point you brought up.

Comment: @KaranSingh, I am not sure what exactly you are asking. But, probably using a fried function can help you.

Comment: @MTMD I wanted to create a virtual function in father class which will be overridden in its child class with protected inheritance, is it possible?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen why is it not advised to create dynamic memory inside constructor?

Comment: Yes. You can achieve that with a friend member. In case you may need more help on that, please ask it as separate question (answering that question here makes it hard for future users to use this post).

Comment: @MTMD doesn't friend class inherits private members also, then how could i get protected inheritance?